# R: projection robin in tmap

Tags: r, maps, geospatial, tmap

I am trying to create map with projection "robin", but I get an error:

```
library(sp)
library(tmap)
data(World)
tm_shape(World, projection = "robin")+tm_borders()+tm_fill(col = 'pop_est_dens')+tm_grid(n.x = 11, n.y = 11)
Error in st_crs.character(x[[shape.id[masterID]]]$projection) : 
  invalid crs: robin
```

What shall I do to get the desired projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using the PROJ4 string to specify the projection; this can be found [with a little googling](https://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/world-robinson/)

```
library(sp)
library(tmap)
data(World)

robin <- "+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

tm_shape(World, projection = robin) + tm_borders() +
  tm_fill(col = 'pop_est_dens') + 
  tm_grid(n.x = 11, n.y = 11)
```

[image]

The map itself seems to be projected okay (Alaska and Australia look very robinsonish) but the grid does not seem quite right I am afraid...